# .ontime not working in python, can't figure out what variable to put

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can't figure out what variable to put in a replacement for `wn`towards the end of the code.

```
#-----import statements----

import turtle as trtl

#-----game configuration----

score1 = 0
score2 = 0

#-----initialize turtle-----

painter1 = trtl.Turtle()
painter1.goto(-100, 0)
painter1.shape("circle")
painter1.fillcolor("red")
painter1.shapesize(3)

painter2 = trtl.Turtle()
painter2.goto(100,0)
painter2.shape("square")
painter2.fillcolor("blue")
painter2.shapesize(3)

score_writer = trtl.Turtle()
score_writer.speed(0)
score_writer.penup()
score_writer.goto(50,-60)
score_writer.setheading(-180)
score_writer.pendown()

x = 0
while (x < 2):
  score_writer.forward(100)
  score_writer.left(-90)
  score_writer.forward(25)
  score_writer.left(-90)
  x += 1
score_writer.ht()

score_writer1 = trtl.Turtle()
score_writer1.penup()
score_writer1.goto(20,-64)
score_writer1.ht()

score_writer2 = trtl.Turtle()
score_writer2.penup()
score_writer2.goto(-30,-64)
score_writer2.ht()

font_setup = ("Arial", 20, "normal")

timer = 5
counter_interval = 1000
timer_up = False

counter =  trtl.Turtle()
counter.penup()
counter.goto(-5,-76)
counter.ht()

#-----game functions--------

def update_score_for_painter1(x,y):
    global score1
    score1 += 1
    score_writer1.clear()
    score_writer1.write(score1, font = font_setup)

def update_score_for_painter2(x,y):
    global score2
    score2 += 1
    score_writer2.clear()
    score_writer2.write(score2, font = font_setup)

timer = 30

def countdown():
  global timer, timer_up
  counter.clear()
  if timer <= 0:
    counter.write("Time's Up", font=font_setup)
    timer_up = True
  else:
    counter.write("Timer: " + str(timer), font=font_setup)
    timer -= 1
    counter.getscreen().ontimer(countdown, counter_interval) 

#---------events----------

painter1.onclick(update_score_for_painter1)
painter2.onclick(update_score_for_painter2)

wn.ontimer(countdown, counter_interval)

trtl.done()
```

Comment: Try `trtl.ontimer()`

Comment: I've tried trtl and counter, for both it says Module 'turtle' has no 'ontime' member

Comment: And you're sure you wrote `ontimer` and not `ontime` as in your error message?  I was basing my answer on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-ontimer-function-in-python/.

Comment: Yep, I used it only twice and both times it says ontimer I don't understand what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working on repl.it

```
screen = trtl.getscreen()
screen.ontimer(countdown, counter_interval)
```

ref link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer